# Makefile split string and pipe it to different target

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to write a simple Makefile to build `.expected` files and compare them but I am failing.

```
APSSCHED=../../bin/apssched
BASE=.:../../base:../../examples
FLAGS=-DCOT
EXAMPLES=../../examples/
CASES=simple-binding1 simple-binding2

# skipping lines doesn't work ...
# run command and skip the first line
%.aps:
    ${APSSCHED} ${FLAGS} -p ${BASE} ${EXAMPLES}/$* | tail -n +2

# get all cases as an array to pipe it to different make targets
# maybe overcomplicating
cases:
    echo ${CASES} | \
    awk '{split($$0,numbers," ")} END {for(n in numbers){ print numbers[n] }}'

# create all .expected files from ${CASES}
build.expected:
    $(MAKE) cases | xargs -n1 -I file /bin/bash -c '$(MAKE) file.build.expected'

# create single .expected file
%.build.expected:
    $(MAKE) $*.aps > $*.expected

# compare result with 
%.compare:
    $(MAKE) $*.aps | diff $*.expected -

# run command for all cases and diff the result with corresponding expected
all:
    $(MAKE) cases | xargs -n1 -I file /bin/bash -c '$(MAKE) file.compare'

clean.expected:
    rm *.expected
```

Running `make` without any target and nothing happens.

> ```
> echo simple-binding1 simple-binding2 | \
> awk '{split($0,numbers," ")} END {for(n in numbers){ print numbers[n] }}'
> simple-binding1
> simple-binding2
> ```

I think the issue is with my `cases` target. I am not sure if I am on the right track.

I appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: It's not that 'nothing happens'. It happens exactly what you wished for: running `make` without specifying target runs your first defined non-implicit target, in this case it executes target `cases`. Your output seems to confirm that. As for all the other code you are basically trying to use `make` in a very non-standard and convoluted way; might help with a longer answer if you could please explain how exactly do you expect it to work? File `.expected` seems to just have output from the command that you immediately want to run again and check if it printed out the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid re-running `make` just to call a different target - it's a performance hit and may be unreliable (depending on rest of the `Makefile`) since separate calls may not be able to track dependencies correctly.

Moreover, I would avoid using `|` - every time a command is concatenated with pipe, exit code of piped command would be exit code of the last command. So a call like `command | tail` would return the exit code of `tail` (which would almost always succeed). Even if the `command` has failed, it would be covered with exit code 0 from `tail` and `make` will not detect the error and will not stop.

Thus said, I tried to rewrite your approach by just creating dependencies between the targets, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
APSSCHED=../../bin/apssched
EXAMPLES=../../examples
BASE=.:../../base:$(EXAMPLES)
FLAGS=-DCOT
CASES=simple-binding1 simple-binding2

# Just for reproducing
$(EXAMPLES)/%.aps: ;

# Generate output and store it in a file
%.output: $(EXAMPLES)/%.aps
        # echo is only for reproducing
        echo $(APSSCHED) $(FLAGS) -p $(BASE) $< > $@

# Copy actual output as expected
%.expected: %.output
        cp -f $< $@

# Compare actual output with expected
.PHONY: %.compare
%.compare: %.output | %.expected
        diff $| $<

# Generate and verify all outputs
.PHONY: all
all: $(addsuffix .compare,$(CASES))

# Regenerate expected output
.PHONY: build.expected
build.expected: $(addsuffix .expected,$(CASES))

.PHONY: clean.expected
clean.expected:
        -rm -f *.expected
```

Now the `make build.expected` will create expected output files, while `make all` or `make` will check the actual output against expected:

```
$ make build.expected
echo ../../bin/apssched -DCOT -p .:../../base:../../examples ../../examples/simple-binding1.aps > simple-binding1.output
cp -f simple-binding1.output simple-binding1.expected
echo ../../bin/apssched -DCOT -p .:../../base:../../examples ../../examples/simple-binding2.aps > simple-binding2.output
cp -f simple-binding2.output simple-binding2.expected
rm simple-binding1.output simple-binding2.output

$ make
echo ../../bin/apssched -DCOT -p .:../../base:../../examples ../../examples/simple-binding1.aps > simple-binding1.output
diff simple-binding1.expected simple-binding1.output
echo ../../bin/apssched -DCOT -p .:../../base:../../examples ../../examples/simple-binding2.aps > simple-binding2.output
diff simple-binding2.expected simple-binding2.output
rm simple-binding1.output simple-binding2.output
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You went above and beyond. Thank you.

Comment: @raspy I am curious what was the reason to use ["order-only-prerequisites"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) for `%.compare`?

Comment: To not generate `%.expected` when it already exists. Otherwise we would probably have it regenerated when output changes, so it would always be the same (i.e. actual output vs. expected output), which probably is not the desired state.

Comment: I am wondering can I get some feedback for this Makefile. I think I did a better job. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259066/simple-makefile-to-build-scala-file-and-running-them